# Определение высоты блока при помощи Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Написал код, чтобы высота картинки была размером как блок для текста, но что то у картинки высота меньше.

```
function carouselService(){
    $('.carousel-service-item').each( function(){
        var ths  = $(this),
            thsh = ths.find('.carousel-service-content').outerHeight();
        $(this).find('.carousel-service-image').css('min-height', thsh);
    });
}carouselService();


       <div class="owl-carousel carousel-service">
            <div class="carousel-service-item">
                <div class="carousel-service-content">
                    <h5>Brand Developme</h5>
                    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</P>
                </div>
                <!-- /carousel-service-content -->

                <div class="carousel-service-image">

                </div>
                <!-- /carousel-service-image -->
            </div>
            <!-- /carousel-service-item -->
       </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: Приложите [mcve]

Comment: я же картинку приложил, что ещё нужно? это же не анимация

Comment: из картинки видно, что размер картинки меньше чем размер блока для текста

Comment: $("element").innerHeight(); так же вроде

Comment: @pavel а вот по вашему куску кода вообще ничего не видно. Если вы ленитесь предоставить воспроизводимый пример, почему кто-то должен не полениться и решить проблему, не зная что решать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.carousel-service-item').each( function(){
    // получаем высоту контента включая padding
    var contentH = $(this).find('.carousel-service-content').innerHeight();
    // устанавливаем фиксированную высоту контейнеру с картинкой
    $(this).find('.carousel-service-image').css('height', contentH);
});
```

обращаю внимание что высота задаётся контейнеру... судя по всему тег "img" потом генерируется? возможно вам необходимо будет прописать css стили для красивого отображения картинки, к примеру:

```
{ width: 100%; height:100%, object-fit: cover; }
```